# Code Completion for WebDriverIO in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I've been struggling all day to get code-completion working in Intellij. I am working on a project that uses cucumber with webdriverio. When you hover over any method you get "Unresolved function or method for ...".

I've tried adding webdriverio as a custom javascript library but it's not working. I've added the directory from (usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriverio/) with no luck. I've tried adding all the files and directories in various formations and nothing has worked.

[image: Notice the squiggly lines]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

At the current time I don't think there is a way for JetBrains products. There is a Sublime package. I talked to one of the authors and he has not written one yet. I'm also looking for one for Webstorm.

Comment: It will be great if they can support auto complete for custom libraries in intellij.